# How can I add a comment in word in a text box?

Tags: microsoft-word

When I highlight a piece of text and try to add a comment to it, the "New Comment" button is grayed out. This occurs in a text box. How can I add a comment?

[image: The toolbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Insert a Frame instead of Text Box`, then you can add comment to it.
You can add **Insert Frame** to the Quick Access Toolbar (All Commands) and use it to draw a frame around selected text. After that use New Comment to write a comment.

[image]

[Click Here to Add new command to Quick Access Toolbar](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T005987_Customizing_the_Quick_Access_Toolbar.html)